# I have add below condition but doesn't match , so what is the reason ? it is directly going else condition

Tags: php

I have add below condition but doesn't match , so what is the reason ? it is directly going else condition

```
if($_FILES['img']['size']="" && $_FILES['img']['name']="")
```

Comment: Edit your question title to be brief

Comment: you are using single `=` use `==` `if($_FILES['img']['size']== "" && $_FILES['img']['name']== "")`

Comment: You need to use == to compare values, not a single =

Answer (score 2):

use `==` for **comparison**. You've used `=` which is for **assignment**, so Use "==" instead "="

```
if($_FILES['img']['size'] == "" && $_FILES['img']['name'] == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use double equals.

Change from:

```
if($_FILES['img']['size']="" && $_FILES['img']['name']="")
```

To:

```
if($_FILES['img']['size']=="" && $_FILES['img']['name']=="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `empty`

```
if(empty($_FILES['img']['size']) && empty($_FILES['img']['name']))
```